# Full Calendar - Display import.calendar.google.com Calendar from Google

Tags: fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I am using FullCalendar (https://fullcalendar.io) to display a calendar widget on my website and displaying one of my public access Google Calendars succesfully - I have an ICS feed calendar which I would also like to display on the calendar - I dont think FullCalendar supports the sync with an ICS file which is a shame - so... I have created a 2nd Google Calendar which syncs with this ICS feed - I would like to get this 2nd Google Calendar to display on my FullCalendar calendar but I get an error as below:

```
Google Calendar API: Not Found Object { domain: "global", reason: "notFound", message: "Not Found" }
```

I think FullCalendar does not support the format of subscribed Google Calendars - e.g. ones in the format of: 123ABC@import.calendar.google.com - It seems ok with 123ABC@group.calendar.google.com only.

Does anyone know how I can get the subscribed calendar feed from Google Calendar into my FullCalendar?

Comment: Have you tried to do it as per the documentation? https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/ is the 2nd link on the documentation page. Also please show your code, it's impossible to help just from a vague description and an error message. The error message is useful, but doesn't say enough.

Comment: Yes - as per question above it works fine pulling in the data from a standard Google Calendar - e.g. one that you can add events to within Google Calendar which has the ID in format "abc123@group.calendar.google.com" - but it wont sync with a subscribed google calendar - e.g. one where the Google Calendar is made up of the content of an ICS feed - which then has the ID format "abc123@import.calendar.google.com"

Comment: hm, i've never tried that, but yeah seemingly perhaps the Google Calendar API wont recognise the ID. Not clear whether it's the Google Calendar API or fullCalendar which is the source of the problem, although the error message suggests it's probably the API. In which case there's probably not a lot you can do about it. The only thing would be to check the source of gcal.js and see if it's anything related to the way fullCalendar queries the API, in case it puts some limitation on what it searches for, somehow. I'm only speculating here, though, I don't know the details of how it works.

Comment: OK - yeh - I guess the formatting ot the subscribed calendar is different and therefore means fullcalendar cant process it which is a shame... I am looking for a way to display the contents of 2 subscribed ICS feeds on one calendar widget which I can style up... I cant seem to find a solution anywhere to achieve this!???

Comment: it could be the formatting, or that the Google API simply doesn't expose calendars from the "import" domain, or as I speculated, fullCalendar doesn't request them properly. Unless you've checked the source and can verify it's something to do with the "formatting" (although the formatting of _what_?). Also worth triple-checking that you actually did make that calendar public :-)

Comment: P.S. you can certainly display data from two or more different feeds in fullCalendar using the eventSources functionality, but obviously it can't be in .ics format. Although, from a quick google, https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/1580 has links to a couple of projects which attempt to convert ics into fullCalendar's JSON format. No word on whether they work, but it might be worth trying them.

Comment: Thanks ADyson - Will have a look.